# Copy paste formulas verbatim

Tags: excel

Say I have a row of 100 cells, each with some formula.

I want to copy them and paste them somewhere else, but with the formulas *verbatim* exactly the same, without changing the reference.

Is there a quick way to do this (i.e. *without macros, without having to add $ signs to the formulas*, etc.)? One might have thought that there is some way to do this through Paste Special, but I don't seem to see any such option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest way I usually do this is using `find > replace`...

Do something like this:

1. Select the cells that have the formulas you want
2. Use the find > replace feature in excel and replace all `=` with some other, **unused** character (I usually use `#`) - This will change them from formulas to plain text
3. Copy those cells and paste them where you want
4. Use the find > replace  feature to replace that other character back to `=`

In effect, you are changing the formula to text, copying and pasting it as the plain text (so preserving the cell references), then changing it back to the original formula.

Hope this helps and makes sense.